# Spock mock with DetachedMockFactory always returns null

Tags: spock

I have a spring boot app where I am using Spock for testing.
I have below classes where I am trying to mock `BankStatementServiceClient.fetch()`. I can see that the bean is correctly wired (bankStatementTestClient is mocked object), but I always get null when calling `bankStatementTestClient.fetch()` from tests.

```groovy
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [SweepTestConfig])
class TestIntSpec extends Specification {
   @Autowired
   BankStatementServiceClient bankStatementTestClient

   def "mock service"() {
       when:
           def result = bankStatementTestClient.fetch() //bankStatementTestClient is autowired correctly
       then:
           result == ["a","b"]
           1 * bankStatementTestClient.fetch() >> ["a","b"]
   }
}
```

```groovy
@TestConfiguration
class SweepTestConfig {
    def mockFactory = new DetachedMockFactory()

    @Bean
    @Primary
    BankStatementServiceClient bankStatementTestClient() {
        return mockFactory.Mock(BankStatementServiceClient)
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class BankStatementServiceClient {
    public List<String> fetch() {
        return Arrays.asList("dummy1", "dummy2");
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you passing @Profile("integration") for test ? i don't see @ActiveProfiles("integration") annotation in the test ?

Comment: I've edited to correct that. I had edited classes a bit to simplify the post and forgot to remove that.

Comment: Tests are working fine. i can see values ["a","b"] returning correctly in the tests. Are you maven or gradle ?

Comment: gradle. I am using spock version 1.3-groovy-2.5

Comment: Test cases are working with testImplementation("org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.4")
    testImplementation("org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5")
    testImplementation("org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.3-groovy-2.5") dependency.